# Can't wrap my head around this function - any help would be appreciated

Tags: functions, theme-customizer

OK so I am working on a theme that utilizes the customizer a lot.

When you change a color for example, the necessary css gets added to the header, but when you click default, the css with the default value remains in the header.

So I went looking for a solution and discovered there was one under my nose the entire time. I found what I was looking for in the custom-header.php file of my theme. I used Twenty Twelve to make this theme so if you can take a look. I took the "twentytwelve_header_style"
and changed it to this:

```
function wpforge_customize_css() {
$header_container = esc_attr(get_theme_mod( 'header_container_background_color' )); 
if ( $header_container == get_theme_mod( 'header_container_background_color', '#e6e6e6' ) ) 
return;
?>
<!--Customizer CSS-->
<style type="text/css" id="wpforge-customizer-css">
.header_container{background-color:<?php echo $header_container; ?>;}
</style>
<!--/Customizer CSS-->
```

I was surprised when it actually worked. No customizer-css showed in the header but when I selected a background color in the customizer, the proper css style showed in the header. Now when I set th value back to default, the css disappeared from the header. I thought to myself AWESOME!!!

So I tried to add another value to the same function and this is what I got:

```
function wpforge_customize_css() {
  $header_container = esc_attr(get_theme_mod( 'header_container_background_color' )); 
  if ( $header_container == get_theme_mod( 'header_container_background_color', '#e6e6e6' ) ) 
    return;
  $header_wrap_width = esc_attr(get_theme_mod( 'header_width' )); 
  if ( $header_wrap_width == get_theme_mod( 'header_width', '64rem' ) ) 
    return;
  ?>
<!--Customizer CSS-->
<style type="text/css" id="wpforge-customizer-css">
.header_container{background-color:<?php echo $header_container; ?>;}
.header_wrap{max-width:<?php echo $header_wrap_width; ?>;}
</style>
<!--/Customizer CSS-->
```

It worked perfect or so I thought. So I tried to add another to it and found that nothing would display until I selected something for one of the other elements, meaning I had to select something for the header container in order for the header wrap to work or show.

I'm no php expert and I cannot write a lick of code to save my life, but I do kind of understand it, enough to the point where I can tinker with it.

So I was wondering if anyone could show me how to write this function properly, so I can add multiple items to it and it will work. Where I can take this:

```
function wpforge_customize_css() {
  $header_container = esc_attr(get_theme_mod( 'header_container_background_color' )); 
  if ( $header_container == get_theme_mod( 'header_container_background_color', '#e6e6e6' ) ) 
    return;
  ?>
<!--Customizer CSS-->
<style type="text/css" id="wpforge-customizer-css">
.header_container{background-color:<?php echo $header_container; ?>;}
</style>
<!--/Customizer CSS-->
```

and make itit like this:

```
function wpforge_customize_css() {
  $header_container = esc_attr(get_theme_mod( 'header_container_background_color' )); 
  if ( $header_container == get_theme_mod( 'header_container_background_color', '#e6e6e6' ) ) 
    return;
  $header_wrap_width = esc_attr(get_theme_mod( 'header_width' )); 
  if ( $header_wrap_width == get_theme_mod( 'header_width', '64rem' ) ) 
    return;
  ?>
<!--Customizer CSS-->
<style type="text/css" id="wpforge-customizer-css">
.header_container{background-color:<?php echo $header_container; ?>;}
.header_wrap{max-width:<?php echo $header_wrap_width; ?>;}
</style>
<!--/Customizer CSS-->
```

and it works without having to select a value for the header_container just so the header_wrapper will appear

any help is greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: Please correct your post title so that it is inline with your actual question. Thank you :-)

Comment: I believe the title conveys what I am looking for, it's about a function which I got working to a certain degree, however I can't "wrap" my head around getting it do what I want it to do. However, do you have something in mind that you believe would be a better title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you return nothing if some of the options doesn't meet your criteria. For example, you are doing this:

```
if ( $header_container == get_theme_mod( 'header_container_background_color', '#e6e6e6' ) ) 
    return;
```

So, if `$header_container` is equal to `#e6e6e6`, the function `return` and stop further execution. You have to change that logic. For example (just a quick example):

```
function wpforge_customize_css() {

    $output = '';

    $header_container = esc_attr(get_theme_mod( 'header_container_background_color' )); 
    if ( $header_container != get_theme_mod( 'header_container_background_color', '#e6e6e6' ) ) {
        $output = '.header_container{background-color: '.$header_container.'}';
    }

    $header_wrap_width = esc_attr(get_theme_mod( 'header_width' )); 
    if ( $header_wrap_width != get_theme_mod( 'header_width', '64rem' ) ) {
        $output = '.header_wrap{background-color: '.$header_wrap_width.'}';
    }

    if( !empty($output) ) {

    ?>
        <!--Customizer CSS-->
        <style type="text/css" id="wpforge-customizer-css">
           <?php echo $output; ?>
        </style>
        <!--/Customizer CSS-->
    <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @cybmeta, bits and pieces of what you provided above worked and everything seems to be working good so far. I am testing each one as I add them in. If I run into an issue I will def come back here and ask for help ;)